# How does recursion consider all possible combinations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I need a recursive solution to the following problem:

You have "n" apples, each with a known weight. Your task is to divide the apples into two groups so that the difference between the weights of the groups is minimal.

The input consists of an integer "n" representing the number of apples, followed by a line with "n" integers p1,p2,…,pn: representing the weight of each apple.

Example Input:

```
5
3 2 7 4 1
```

Example Output:

```
1
```

Explanation: Group 1 has weights 2, 3 and 4 (total weight 9), and group 2 has weights 1 and 7 (total weight 8).

Constraints:
1 ≤ n ≤ 20
1 ≤ pi ≤ 10^9

Here is a possible solution:

```py
def divide_apples(index, group1_weight, group2_weight, apple_weights):
    # Base case: If all apples have been considered, return the difference in weights
    if index == len(apple_weights):
        return abs(group1_weight - group2_weight)
    
    # Recursive calls:
    # Include current apple weight in group 1
    diff1 = divide_apples(index + 1, group1_weight + apple_weights[index], group2_weight, apple_weights)
    # Include current apple weight in group 2
    diff2 = divide_apples(index + 1, group1_weight, group2_weight + apple_weights[index], apple_weights)
    
    # Return the minimum difference obtained
    return min(diff1, diff2)

# Main code
n = int(input())  # Read the number of apples
apple_weights = list(map(int, input().split()))  # Read the apple weights

# Call the divide_apples function with initial values
minimum_difference = divide_apples(0, 0, 0, apple_weights)
print(minimum_difference)
```

The solution solves the problem using recursion and considers all possible combinations to find the minimum difference between the weights of the two groups. But I can't understand how, don't both the functions just call themselves and keep incrementing the values of the array (apple_weights) to the groupweight and then terminate as they reach len(apple_weight) and the absolute difference between the two groups turn out to be zero in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first apple you make 2 recursive calls.

Then for the second apple, each of these two recursive calls makes two recursive calls; so at that level we have 4 recursive calls.

Then for the third apple, each of these 4 recursive calls make 2 recursive calls, so at that level we have 8 recursive calls.

Etc.

The recursive calls end up making the following tree, where `{}{}` represents the two groups, and `/ \` represents the two different recursive calls made by your function:

```
                             {}{}
                  /                         \
             {1}{}                           {}{1}
            /     \                         /     \
    {12}{}           {1}{2}         {2}{1}           {}{12}
      / \             / \             / \             / \
{123}{} {12}{3} {13}{2} {1}{23} {23}{1} {2}{13} {3}{12} {}{123}
```

See how after the third level of recursive calls, we have all 8 combinations of placing apples 1,2,3 into the two groups.

Comment: The stack tree is an excellent visualization.

Answer (score 2):

The recursive calls are not affecting each other. You can think of it as "splitting the timeline". The first recursive call represents the scenario:

> If we place `apple_weights[index]` in the **first** group, what would be the minimum difference?

And the second recursive call represents:

> If we place `apple_weights[index]` in the **second** group, what would be the minimium difference?

It then compares those two scenarios, and returns the smaller difference. This works because eventually there'll be no more apples to add, so the last call knows exactly what are the two possible differences. It then bubbles up that result, resolving all the open scenarios before it.